# Taking subsets of a pytorch dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, torch, pytorch

I have a network which I want to train on some dataset (as an example, say `CIFAR10`). I can create data loader object via

```
trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
```

My question is as follows: Suppose I want to make several different training iterations. Let's say I want at first to train the network on all images in odd positions, then on all images in even positions and so on. In order to do that, I need to be able to access to those images. Unfortunately, it seems that `trainset` does not allow such access. That is, trying to do `trainset[:1000]` or more generally `trainset[mask]` will throw an error.

I could do instead

```
trainset.train_data=trainset.train_data[mask]
trainset.train_labels=trainset.train_labels[mask]
```

and then

```
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                              shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
```

However, that will force me to create a new copy of the full dataset in each iteration (as I already changed `trainset.train_data` so I will need to redefine `trainset`). Is there some way to avoid it?

Ideally, I would like to have something "equivalent" to

```
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset[mask], batch_size=4,
                                              shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can define a custom sampler for the dataset loader avoiding recreating the dataset (just creating a new loader for each different sampling).

```
class YourSampler(Sampler):
    def __init__(self, mask):
        self.mask = mask

    def __iter__(self):
        return (self.indices[i] for i in torch.nonzero(self.mask))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.mask)

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)

sampler1 = YourSampler(your_mask)
sampler2 = YourSampler(your_other_mask)
trainloader_sampler1 = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                          sampler = sampler1, shuffle=False, num_workers=2)
trainloader_sampler2 = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                          sampler = sampler2, shuffle=False, num_workers=2)
```

PS: You can find more info here: http://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/utils/data/sampler.html#Sampler

Comment: Thanks! One small remark: apparently sampler is not compatible with shuffle, so in order to achieve the same result one can do: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                          sampler=SubsetRandomSampler(np.where(mask)[0]),shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

Comment: Keep in mind that a `list` of indices is a valid argument for `sampler` since it implements `__len__` and `__iter__`. This kind of circumvents the need for a custom sampler class.

Comment: from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler

Answer (score 112):

[`torch.utils.data.Subset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset) is easier, supports `shuffle`, and doesn't require writing your own sampler:

```py
import torchvision
import torch

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=None)

evens = list(range(0, len(trainset), 2))
odds = list(range(1, len(trainset), 2))
trainset_1 = torch.utils.data.Subset(trainset, evens)
trainset_2 = torch.utils.data.Subset(trainset, odds)

trainloader_1 = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset_1, batch_size=4,
                                            shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
trainloader_2 = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset_2, batch_size=4,
                                            shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
```

Comment: Converting `evens` and `odds` to a list is not necessary--at least in torch 1.5.0, `Subset` accepts generators: `ts1 = Subset(trainset, range(0, len(trainset), 2))`

Comment: It doesn't allow filtering by class, just by the dataset original order, does it?

Comment: @user650654 Slighlty off-topic, but `range` is not a generator.

Comment: the index set must be a python `Sequence`. i.e. `list`, `tuple` or `range`